# Scroll bar script stops working after jQuery .load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have installed a jQuery scroll plugin which basically just makes the scroll look better, the problem is I have a function which will reload a large part of the page (which has to be done in the program) and the div's that scroll are part of this.

.load:

```
$('.show_page').load('events.php');
```

I know of the:

```
$(document).on(...,...,function(e){
```

tactic, but the script is very long and to complex for this, the main controlling function for the scroll plugin (i think) is this part(in document load):

```
    scroll_bar = $('.cndr_sidebar_inner').jScrollPane(
    {
        mouseWheelSpeed: 30,
        autoReinitialise: true,
        maintainPosition: false,
        animateScroll:true
    }).data('jsp');
```

and then there is this part(out side doc load):

```
    (function (factory) {
    if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        // Node/CommonJS style for Browserify
        module.exports = factory;
    } else {
        // Browser globals
        factory(jQuery);
    }
}(function ($) {

    var toFix = ['wheel', 'mousewheel', 'DOMMouseScroll', 'MozMousePixelScroll'];
    var toBind = 'onwheel' in document || document.documentMode >= 9 ? ['wheel'] : ['mousewheel', 'DomMouseScroll', 'MozMousePixelScroll'];
    var lowestDelta, lowestDeltaXY;

    if ( $.event.fixHooks ) {
        for ( var i = toFix.length; i; ) {
            $.event.fixHooks[ toFix[--i] ] = $.event.mouseHooks;
        }
    }

    $.event.special.mousewheel = {
        setup: function() {
            if ( this.addEventListener ) {
                for ( var i = toBind.length; i; ) {
                    this.addEventListener( toBind[--i], handler, false );
                }
            } else {
                this.onmousewheel = handler;
            }
        },

        teardown: function() {
            if ( this.removeEventListener ) {
                for ( var i = toBind.length; i; ) {
                    this.removeEventListener( toBind[--i], handler, false );
                }
            } else {
                this.onmousewheel = null;
            }
        }
    };

    $.fn.extend({
        mousewheel: function(fn) {
            return fn ? this.bind("mousewheel", fn) : this.trigger("mousewheel");
        },

        unmousewheel: function(fn) {
            return this.unbind("mousewheel", fn);
        }
    });

    function handler(event) {
        var orgEvent = event || window.event,
            args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1),
            delta = 0,
            deltaX = 0,
            deltaY = 0,
            absDelta = 0,
            absDeltaXY = 0,
            fn;
        event = $.event.fix(orgEvent);
        event.type = "mousewheel";

        // Old school scrollwheel delta
        if ( orgEvent.wheelDelta ) { delta = orgEvent.wheelDelta; }
        if ( orgEvent.detail )     { delta = orgEvent.detail * -1; }

        // New school wheel delta (wheel event)
        if ( orgEvent.deltaY ) {
            deltaY = orgEvent.deltaY * -1;
            delta  = deltaY;
        }
        if ( orgEvent.deltaX ) {
            deltaX = orgEvent.deltaX;
            delta  = deltaX * -1;
        }

        // Webkit
        if ( orgEvent.wheelDeltaY !== undefined ) { deltaY = orgEvent.wheelDeltaY; }
        if ( orgEvent.wheelDeltaX !== undefined ) { deltaX = orgEvent.wheelDeltaX * -1; }

        // Look for lowest delta to normalize the delta values
        absDelta = Math.abs(delta);
        if ( !lowestDelta || absDelta < lowestDelta ) { lowestDelta = absDelta; }
        absDeltaXY = Math.max(Math.abs(deltaY), Math.abs(deltaX));
        if ( !lowestDeltaXY || absDeltaXY < lowestDeltaXY ) { lowestDeltaXY = absDeltaXY; }

        // Get a whole value for the deltas
        fn = delta > 0 ? 'floor' : 'ceil';
        delta  = Math[fn](delta / lowestDelta);
        deltaX = Math[fn](deltaX / lowestDeltaXY);
        deltaY = Math[fn](deltaY / lowestDeltaXY);

        // Add event and delta to the front of the arguments
        args.unshift(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY);

        return ($.event.dispatch || $.event.handle).apply(this, args);
    }

}));
```

and finally the core programming for it(also out of doc load):

```
!function(a,b,c){a.fn.jScrollPane=function(d){function e(d,e){function f(b){var e,h,j,l,m,n,q=!1,r=!1;if(P=b,Q===c)m=d.scrollTop(),n=d.scrollLeft(),d.css({overflow:"hidden",padding:0}),R=d.innerWidth()+tb,S=d.innerHeight(),d.width(R),Q=a('<div class="jspPane" />').css("padding",sb).append(d.children()),T=a('<div class="jspContainer" />').css({width:R+"px",height:S+"px"}).append(Q).appendTo(d);else{if(d.css("width",""),q=P.stickToBottom&&C(),r=P.stickToRight&&D(),l=d.innerWidth()+tb!=R||d.outerHeight()!=S,l&&(R=d.innerWidth()+tb,S=d.innerHeight(),T.css({width:R+"px",height:S+"px"})),!l&&ub==U&&Q.outerHeight()==V)return d.width(R),void 0;ub=U,Q.css("width",""),d.width(R),T.find(">.jspVerticalBar,>.jspHorizontalBar").remove().end()}Q.css("overflow","auto"),U=b.contentWidth?b.contentWidth:Q[0].scrollWidth,V=Q[0].scrollHeight,Q.css("overflow",""),W=U/R,X=V/S,Y=X>1,Z=W>1,Z||Y?(d.addClass("jspScrollable"),e=P.maintainPosition&&(ab||db),e&&(h=A(),j=B()),g(),i(),k(),e&&(y(r?U-R:h,!1),x(q?V-S:j,!1)),H(),E(),N(),P.enableKeyboardNavigation&&J(),P.clickOnTrack&&o(),L(),P.hijackInternalLinks&&M()):(d.removeClass("jspScrollable"),Q.css({top:0,left:0,width:T.width()-tb}),F(),I(),K(),p()),P.autoReinitialise&&!rb?rb=setInterval(function(){f(P)},P.autoReinitialiseDelay):!P.autoReinitialise&&rb&&clearInterval(rb),m&&d.scrollTop(0)&&x(m,!1),n&&d.scrollLeft(0)&&y(n,!1),d.trigger("jsp-initialised",[Z||Y])}function g(){Y&&(T.append(a('<div class="jspVerticalBar" />').append(a('<div class="jspCap jspCapTop" />'),a('<div class="jspTrack" />').append(a('<div class="jspDrag" />').append(a('<div class="jspDragTop" />'),a('<div class="jspDragBottom" />'))),a('<div class="jspCap jspCapBottom" />'))),eb=T.find(">.jspVerticalBar"),fb=eb.find(">.jspTrack"),$=fb.find(">.jspDrag"),P.showArrows&&(jb=a('<a href="#" class="jspArrow jspArrowUp" />').bind("mousedown.jsp",m(0,-1)).bind("click.jsp",G),kb=a('<a href="#" class="jspArrow jspArrowDown" />').bind("mousedown.jsp",m(0,1)).bind("click.jsp",G),P.arrowScrollOnHover&&(jb.bind("mouseover.jsp",m(0,-1,jb)),kb.bind("mouseover.jsp",m(0,1,kb))),l(fb,P.verticalArrowPositions,jb,kb)),hb=S,T.find(">.jspVerticalBar>.jspCap:visible,>.jspVerticalBar>.jspArrow").each(function(){hb-=a(this).outerHeight()}),$.hover(function(){$.addClass("jspHover")},function(){$.removeClass("jspHover")}).bind("mousedown.jsp",function(b){a("html").bind("dragstart.jsp selectstart.jsp",G),$.addClass("jspActive");var c=b.pageY-$.position().top;return a("html").bind("mousemove.jsp",function(a){r(a.pageY-c,!1)}).bind("mouseup.jsp mouseleave.jsp",q),!1}),h())}function h(){fb.height(hb+"px"),ab=0,gb=P.verticalGutter+fb.outerWidth(),Q.width(R-gb-tb);try{0===eb.position().left&&Q.css("margin-left",gb+"px")}catch(a){}}function i(){Z&&(T.append(a('<div class="jspHorizontalBar" />').append(a('<div class="jspCap jspCapLeft" />'),a('<div class="jspTrack" />').append(a('<div class="jspDrag" />').append(a('<div class="jspDragLeft" />'),a('<div class="jspDragRight" />'))),a('<div class="jspCap jspCapRight" />'))),lb=T.find(">.jspHorizontalBar"),mb=lb.find(">.jspTrack"),bb=mb.find(">.jspDrag"),P.showArrows&&(pb=a('<a href="#" class="jspArrow jspArrowLeft" />').bind("mousedown.jsp",m(-1,0)).bind("click.jsp",G),qb=a('<a href="#" class="jspArrow jspArrowRight" />').bind("mousedown.jsp",m(1,0)).bind("click.jsp",G),P.arrowScrollOnHover&&(pb.bind("mouseover.jsp",m(-1,0,pb)),qb.bind("mouseover.jsp",m(1,0,qb))),l(mb,P.horizontalArrowPositions,pb,qb)),bb.hover(function(){bb.addClass("jspHover")},function(){bb.removeClass("jspHover")}).bind("mousedown.jsp",function(b){a("html").bind("dragstart.jsp selectstart.jsp",G),bb.addClass("jspActive");var c=b.pageX-bb.position().left;return a("html").bind("mousemove.jsp",function(a){t(a.pageX-c,!1)}).bind("mouseup.jsp mouseleave.jsp",q),!1}),nb=T.innerWidth(),j())}function j(){T.find(">.jspHorizontalBar>.jspCap:visible,>.jspHorizontalBar>.jspArrow").each(function(){nb-=a(this).outerWidth()}),mb.width(nb+"px"),db=0}function k(){if(Z&&Y){var b=mb.outerHeight(),c=fb.outerWidth();hb-=b,a(lb).find(">.jspCap:visible,>.jspArrow").each(function(){nb+=a(this).outerWidth()}),nb-=c,S-=c,R-=b,mb.parent().append(a('<div class="jspCorner" />').css("width",b+"px")),h(),j()}Z&&Q.width(T.outerWidth()-tb+"px"),V=Q.outerHeight(),X=V/S,Z&&(ob=Math.ceil(1/W*nb),ob>P.horizontalDragMaxWidth?ob=P.horizontalDragMaxWidth:ob<P.horizontalDragMinWidth&&(ob=P.horizontalDragMinWidth),bb.width(ob+"px"),cb=nb-ob,u(db)),Y&&(ib=Math.ceil(1/X*hb),ib>P.verticalDragMaxHeight?ib=P.verticalDragMaxHeight:ib<P.verticalDragMinHeight&&(ib=P.verticalDragMinHeight),$.height(ib+"px"),_=hb-ib,s(ab))}function l(a,b,c,d){var e,f="before",g="after";"os"==b&&(b=/Mac/.test(navigator.platform)?"after":"split"),b==f?g=b:b==g&&(f=b,e=c,c=d,d=e),a[f](c)[g](d)}function m(a,b,c){return function(){return n(a,b,this,c),this.blur(),!1}}function n(b,c,d,e){d=a(d).addClass("jspActive");var f,g,h=!0,i=function(){0!==b&&vb.scrollByX(b*P.arrowButtonSpeed),0!==c&&vb.scrollByY(c*P.arrowButtonSpeed),g=setTimeout(i,h?P.initialDelay:P.arrowRepeatFreq),h=!1};i(),f=e?"mouseout.jsp":"mouseup.jsp",e=e||a("html"),e.bind(f,function(){d.removeClass("jspActive"),g&&clearTimeout(g),g=null,e.unbind(f)})}function o(){p(),Y&&fb.bind("mousedown.jsp",function(b){if(b.originalTarget===c||b.originalTarget==b.currentTarget){var d,e=a(this),f=e.offset(),g=b.pageY-f.top-ab,h=!0,i=function(){var a=e.offset(),c=b.pageY-a.top-ib/2,f=S*P.scrollPagePercent,k=_*f/(V-S);if(0>g)ab-k>c?vb.scrollByY(-f):r(c);else{if(!(g>0))return j(),void 0;c>ab+k?vb.scrollByY(f):r(c)}d=setTimeout(i,h?P.initialDelay:P.trackClickRepeatFreq),h=!1},j=function(){d&&clearTimeout(d),d=null,a(document).unbind("mouseup.jsp",j)};return i(),a(document).bind("mouseup.jsp",j),!1}}),Z&&mb.bind("mousedown.jsp",function(b){if(b.originalTarget===c||b.originalTarget==b.currentTarget){var d,e=a(this),f=e.offset(),g=b.pageX-f.left-db,h=!0,i=function(){var a=e.offset(),c=b.pageX-a.left-ob/2,f=R*P.scrollPagePercent,k=cb*f/(U-R);if(0>g)db-k>c?vb.scrollByX(-f):t(c);else{if(!(g>0))return j(),void 0;c>db+k?vb.scrollByX(f):t(c)}d=setTimeout(i,h?P.initialDelay:P.trackClickRepeatFreq),h=!1},j=function(){d&&clearTimeout(d),d=null,a(document).unbind("mouseup.jsp",j)};return i(),a(document).bind("mouseup.jsp",j),!1}})}function p(){mb&&mb.unbind("mousedown.jsp"),fb&&fb.unbind("mousedown.jsp")}function q(){a("html").unbind("dragstart.jsp selectstart.jsp mousemove.jsp mouseup.jsp mouseleave.jsp"),$&&$.removeClass("jspActive"),bb&&bb.removeClass("jspActive")}function r(a,b){Y&&(0>a?a=0:a>_&&(a=_),b===c&&(b=P.animateScroll),b?vb.animate($,"top",a,s):($.css("top",a),s(a)))}function s(a){a===c&&(a=$.position().top),T.scrollTop(0),ab=a;var b=0===ab,e=ab==_,f=a/_,g=-f*(V-S);(wb!=b||yb!=e)&&(wb=b,yb=e,d.trigger("jsp-arrow-change",[wb,yb,xb,zb])),v(b,e),Q.css("top",g),d.trigger("jsp-scroll-y",[-g,b,e]).trigger("scroll")}function t(a,b){Z&&(0>a?a=0:a>cb&&(a=cb),b===c&&(b=P.animateScroll),b?vb.animate(bb,"left",a,u):(bb.css("left",a),u(a)))}function u(a){a===c&&(a=bb.position().left),T.scrollTop(0),db=a;var b=0===db,e=db==cb,f=a/cb,g=-f*(U-R);(xb!=b||zb!=e)&&(xb=b,zb=e,d.trigger("jsp-arrow-change",[wb,yb,xb,zb])),w(b,e),Q.css("left",g),d.trigger("jsp-scroll-x",[-g,b,e]).trigger("scroll")}function v(a,b){P.showArrows&&(jb[a?"addClass":"removeClass"]("jspDisabled"),kb[b?"addClass":"removeClass"]("jspDisabled"))}function w(a,b){P.showArrows&&(pb[a?"addClass":"removeClass"]("jspDisabled"),qb[b?"addClass":"removeClass"]("jspDisabled"))}function x(a,b){var c=a/(V-S);r(c*_,b)}function y(a,b){var c=a/(U-R);t(c*cb,b)}function z(b,c,d){var e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n=0,o=0;try{e=a(b)}catch(p){return}for(f=e.outerHeight(),g=e.outerWidth(),T.scrollTop(0),T.scrollLeft(0);!e.is(".jspPane");)if(n+=e.position().top,o+=e.position().left,e=e.offsetParent(),/^body|html$/i.test(e[0].nodeName))return;h=B(),j=h+S,h>n||c?l=n-P.verticalGutter:n+f>j&&(l=n-S+f+P.verticalGutter),isNaN(l)||x(l,d),i=A(),k=i+R,i>o||c?m=o-P.horizontalGutter:o+g>k&&(m=o-R+g+P.horizontalGutter),isNaN(m)||y(m,d)}function A(){return-Q.position().left}function B(){return-Q.position().top}function C(){var a=V-S;return a>20&&a-B()<10}function D(){var a=U-R;return a>20&&a-A()<10}function E(){T.unbind(Bb).bind(Bb,function(a,b,c,d){var e=db,f=ab;return vb.scrollBy(c*P.mouseWheelSpeed,-d*P.mouseWheelSpeed,!1),e==db&&f==ab})}function F(){T.unbind(Bb)}function G(){return!1}function H(){Q.find(":input,a").unbind("focus.jsp").bind("focus.jsp",function(a){z(a.target,!1)})}function I(){Q.find(":input,a").unbind("focus.jsp")}function J(){function b(){var a=db,b=ab;switch(c){case 40:vb.scrollByY(P.keyboardSpeed,!1);break;case 38:vb.scrollByY(-P.keyboardSpeed,!1);break;case 34:case 32:vb.scrollByY(S*P.scrollPagePercent,!1);break;case 33:vb.scrollByY(-S*P.scrollPagePercent,!1);break;case 39:vb.scrollByX(P.keyboardSpeed,!1);break;case 37:vb.scrollByX(-P.keyboardSpeed,!1)}return e=a!=db||b!=ab}var c,e,f=[];Z&&f.push(lb[0]),Y&&f.push(eb[0]),Q.focus(function(){d.focus()}),d.attr("tabindex",0).unbind("keydown.jsp keypress.jsp").bind("keydown.jsp",function(d){if(d.target===this||f.length&&a(d.target).closest(f).length){var g=db,h=ab;switch(d.keyCode){case 40:case 38:case 34:case 32:case 33:case 39:case 37:c=d.keyCode,b();break;case 35:x(V-S),c=null;break;case 36:x(0),c=null}return e=d.keyCode==c&&g!=db||h!=ab,!e}}).bind("keypress.jsp",function(a){return a.keyCode==c&&b(),!e}),P.hideFocus?(d.css("outline","none"),"hideFocus"in T[0]&&d.attr("hideFocus",!0)):(d.css("outline",""),"hideFocus"in T[0]&&d.attr("hideFocus",!1))}function K(){d.attr("tabindex","-1").removeAttr("tabindex").unbind("keydown.jsp keypress.jsp")}function L(){if(location.hash&&location.hash.length>1){var b,c,d=escape(location.hash.substr(1));try{b=a("#"+d+', a[name="'+d+'"]')}catch(e){return}b.length&&Q.find(d)&&(0===T.scrollTop()?c=setInterval(function(){T.scrollTop()>0&&(z(b,!0),a(document).scrollTop(T.position().top),clearInterval(c))},50):(z(b,!0),a(document).scrollTop(T.position().top)))}}function M(){a(document.body).data("jspHijack")||(a(document.body).data("jspHijack",!0),a(document.body).delegate("a[href*=#]","click",function(c){var d,e,f,g,h,i,j=this.href.substr(0,this.href.indexOf("#")),k=location.href;if(-1!==location.href.indexOf("#")&&(k=location.href.substr(0,location.href.indexOf("#"))),j===k){d=escape(this.href.substr(this.href.indexOf("#")+1));try{e=a("#"+d+', a[name="'+d+'"]')}catch(l){return}e.length&&(f=e.closest(".jspScrollable"),g=f.data("jsp"),g.scrollToElement(e,!0),f[0].scrollIntoView&&(h=a(b).scrollTop(),i=e.offset().top,(h>i||i>h+a(b).height())&&f[0].scrollIntoView()),c.preventDefault())}}))}function N(){var a,b,c,d,e,f=!1;T.unbind("touchstart.jsp touchmove.jsp touchend.jsp click.jsp-touchclick").bind("touchstart.jsp",function(g){var h=g.originalEvent.touches[0];a=A(),b=B(),c=h.pageX,d=h.pageY,e=!1,f=!0}).bind("touchmove.jsp",function(g){if(f){var h=g.originalEvent.touches[0],i=db,j=ab;return vb.scrollTo(a+c-h.pageX,b+d-h.pageY),e=e||Math.abs(c-h.pageX)>5||Math.abs(d-h.pageY)>5,i==db&&j==ab}}).bind("touchend.jsp",function(){f=!1}).bind("click.jsp-touchclick",function(){return e?(e=!1,!1):void 0})}function O(){var a=B(),b=A();d.removeClass("jspScrollable").unbind(".jsp"),d.replaceWith(Ab.append(Q.children())),Ab.scrollTop(a),Ab.scrollLeft(b),rb&&clearInterval(rb)}var P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,$,_,ab,bb,cb,db,eb,fb,gb,hb,ib,jb,kb,lb,mb,nb,ob,pb,qb,rb,sb,tb,ub,vb=this,wb=!0,xb=!0,yb=!1,zb=!1,Ab=d.clone(!1,!1).empty(),Bb=a.fn.mwheelIntent?"mwheelIntent.jsp":"mousewheel.jsp";"border-box"===d.css("box-sizing")?(sb=0,tb=0):(sb=d.css("paddingTop")+" "+d.css("paddingRight")+" "+d.css("paddingBottom")+" "+d.css("paddingLeft"),tb=(parseInt(d.css("paddingLeft"),10)||0)+(parseInt(d.css("paddingRight"),10)||0)),a.extend(vb,{reinitialise:function(b){b=a.extend({},P,b),f(b)},scrollToElement:function(a,b,c){z(a,b,c)},scrollTo:function(a,b,c){y(a,c),x(b,c)},scrollToX:function(a,b){y(a,b)},scrollToY:function(a,b){x(a,b)},scrollToPercentX:function(a,b){y(a*(U-R),b)},scrollToPercentY:function(a,b){x(a*(V-S),b)},scrollBy:function(a,b,c){vb.scrollByX(a,c),vb.scrollByY(b,c)},scrollByX:function(a,b){var c=A()+Math[0>a?"floor":"ceil"](a),d=c/(U-R);t(d*cb,b)},scrollByY:function(a,b){var c=B()+Math[0>a?"floor":"ceil"](a),d=c/(V-S);r(d*_,b)},positionDragX:function(a,b){t(a,b)},positionDragY:function(a,b){r(a,b)},animate:function(a,b,c,d){var e={};e[b]=c,a.animate(e,{duration:P.animateDuration,easing:P.animateEase,queue:!1,step:d})},getContentPositionX:function(){return A()},getContentPositionY:function(){return B()},getContentWidth:function(){return U},getContentHeight:function(){return V},getPercentScrolledX:function(){return A()/(U-R)},getPercentScrolledY:function(){return B()/(V-S)},getIsScrollableH:function(){return Z},getIsScrollableV:function(){return Y},getContentPane:function(){return Q},scrollToBottom:function(a){r(_,a)},hijackInternalLinks:a.noop,destroy:function(){O()}}),f(e)}return d=a.extend({},a.fn.jScrollPane.defaults,d),a.each(["arrowButtonSpeed","trackClickSpeed","keyboardSpeed"],function(){d[this]=d[this]||d.speed}),this.each(function(){var b=a(this),c=b.data("jsp");c?c.reinitialise(d):(a("script",b).filter('[type="text/javascript"],:not([type])').remove(),c=new e(b,d),b.data("jsp",c))})},a.fn.jScrollPane.defaults={showArrows:!1,maintainPosition:!0,stickToBottom:!1,stickToRight:!1,clickOnTrack:!0,autoReinitialise:!1,autoReinitialiseDelay:500,verticalDragMinHeight:0,verticalDragMaxHeight:99999,horizontalDragMinWidth:0,horizontalDragMaxWidth:99999,contentWidth:c,animateScroll:!1,animateDuration:300,animateEase:"linear",hijackInternalLinks:!1,verticalGutter:4,horizontalGutter:4,mouseWheelSpeed:3,arrowButtonSpeed:0,arrowRepeatFreq:50,arrowScrollOnHover:!1,trackClickSpeed:0,trackClickRepeatFreq:70,verticalArrowPositions:"split",horizontalArrowPositions:"split",enableKeyboardNavigation:!0,hideFocus:!1,keyboardSpeed:0,initialDelay:300,speed:30,scrollPagePercent:.8}}(jQuery,this);
```

Comment: You'll have to trigger the scroll plugin again after AJAX content has loaded.

Comment: when you reload the page, what is probably happening is that as the DOM is changed, so does all the stuff bound to it, including your fancy scroll plugin. The easy fix would be to put a callback in your `$.load()` call that re-initializes the plugins on the new DOM content.

Comment: sorry i am pretty new at this, how is this done?

Comment: Whenever you finish changing the page, call `.jScrollPane({...})` again, using the same options.

Comment: The documentation for $.load can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/load/ Going on that, you'd do something like: `$.load('page', function(){ .jScrollPane({...}); });`

Comment: most probably doing it wrong but it didn't work: `$('.show_page')load('page', function(){ .jScrollPane({mouseWheelSpeed: 30, autoReinitialise: true, maintainPosition: false, animateScroll:true}); });`

Comment: i have just seen the "."load mistake i made but it still does not work it now will not even load the php, also replaced "page" with "events.php"

Comment: ok the head ache is gone, i was being a spoon, heres the fix: `$('.show_page').load('events.php', function(){ scroll_bar = $('.cndr_sidebar_inner').jScrollPane(
  {
   mouseWheelSpeed: 30,
   autoReinitialise: true,
   maintainPosition: false,
   animateScroll:true
  }).data('jsp'); });`